# How to pass non required fields through FormRequest?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using FormRequest for Validation. 
I'm creating record in DB. There a some fields which are not required, how can i get them through FormRequest. At, the moment i'm only getting fields which are in rules() method.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CategoryRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title_tr' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'description_tr' => 'required',
        'parent_id' => 'required',
        'seo_title_tr' => 'required',
        'meta_description_tr' => 'required'
    ];
}

public function messages(){
    return [
        'title_tr.required' => trans('admin.category.validation_errors.title_tr'),
        'description_tr.required' => trans('admin.category.validation_errors.description_tr'),
        'seo_title_tr.required' => trans('admin.category.validation_errors.seo_title_tr'),
        'meta_description_tr.required' => trans('admin.category.validation_errors.meta_description_tr'),
    ];
}
}
```

Comment: Please can you show your controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [sometimes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

> Validating When Present In some situations, you may wish to run
>   validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the
>   input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to
>   your rule list:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'sometimes',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it `nullable` as shown below.

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // ...
        'not_required_field' => 'nullable',
    ];
}
```